# The ansible.cfg file specifies the python interpreter as python3, but it doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

I want to change the Python version that my Ansible instance uses to Python3, and specified `python3` as my Python interpreter in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg. But when I check with `ansible --version`, the version that is actually used is still 2.7.5.

I downloaded Python3 and specified `/usr/bin/python3` as a softlink, and then added interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3 under [defaults] in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg like this

```
[defaults]
interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3
```

according to the [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file), and then used `ansible --version` to see if the interpreter changed, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think this is a simple misunderstanding between the difference between python being used _for ansible_ from the python, per inventory host, used **by** ansible. Think of it as the difference between you running `which python3` from your terminal, and you running `ssh some-host.example.com which python`

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant, why would you run ```which python3 ```locally and then run ```which python``` remotely, what I want to do is change the default version of the ansible interpreter.

Comment: Ansible which is a Python application run on your controller node, ships on remote node and use the remote node's Python to execute the shipped material. The `interpreter_python` configuration is to adapt the path on the remote nodes, not on the controller. And doing `ansible --version` gives you the version of Python on your controller.